# Consul.IO - How to public service domain in local network for DNS Lookup

Tags: windows, consul

In Windows, when I setup Consul service for Service discovery in local network, I used DNS Interface for query service. But when I query service with this command

```
dig -x 127.0.0.1 -p 53 consul.service.consul +short
```

And it returned nothing.
Currently, my local network DNS address is `10.18.200.103`. But when I changed to Consul server `10.18.200.202`, it worked and return correct data.
I want to know how can my local DNS server find the domain of Consul services without changing DNS to Consul server

Answer (score 2):

You can set your local DNS as recursor in consul config, then set consul as your primary DNS server and your normal DNS as secondary. This will pass requests through consul first.

If consul is up, it will resolve *.consul domain and pass everything else to recursors. If consul is down, OS will pass request to secondary DNS and it will still end up resolved.

```
"recursors": [ "10.18.200.103" ],
```

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html

Comment: It saves my day. Thanks a lot